# Transpose matrix

Tags: r

I have a csv file with two colums `transid` and `item`. It has the following values

```
1 232
1 123
1 232
1 234
1 435
2 435
2 453
2 454
```

I want to convert it into this format.

`232 123 232 234 435` in the first row
`435 453 454` in the second row
Basically the first column gives the transaction id and the second column gives the products in that transaction id,so i want to convert it as one row per transaction with all the products...

Comment: This question is better suited for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

The data frame:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "1 232
1 123
1 232
1 234
1 435
2 435
2 453
2 454")
names(dat) <- c("transid", "item")
```

You can use `tapply` to transpose (`t`) the values in `item` for each unique `transid`. The function `rbind.fill.matrix` from the `plyr` package can be used to combine the rows.

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill.matrix(tapply(dat$item, dat$transid, t))
#        1   2   3   4   5
# [1,] 232 123 232 234 435
# [2,] 435 453 454  NA  NA
```

Comment: ThankYou Sven, I tried using your code...But I got a error message saying "cannot allocate vector of size 736.2 Mb" is that because of the size of my csv file. I have around 7 lakh rows in csv file which i read into R

Comment: @Kishore Do you get this error when you read the csv file or when you run my code?

Comment: I got that error when I ran your code...so i think that's because of the size of the dataset..so now I'm trying to import only sample data...about 230 rows and now it's working fine...   I ran the code below.....datfinal<-rbind.fill.matrix(tapply(dat$PRODUCT_ID,dat$TransId,t))
head(datfinal,5)
rules <- apriori(dat, parameter = list(supp = 0.001, conf = 0.8)) ....once I ran this I'm getting an error message saying columns 1,2 not logical or factor use as.logical or a factor...Please let me know how to go about this

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (using @Svens data set)

```
library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(split(dat$item, dat$transid), byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5] 
# [1,] "232" "123" "232" "234" "435"
# [2,] "435" "453" "454" NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` option would be to assign the length (`'length<-'`)of the list ("lst") elements to the maximum length (`max(sapply(lst,..)`) of the element.  This will pad NAs for those elements having less length compared to the maximum.

```
  lst <- split(dat$item, dat$transid)
  t(sapply(lst, `length<-`, max(sapply(lst, length))))
  # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  #1  232  123  232  234  435
  #2  435  453  454   NA   NA
```

#### data

```
 dat <- structure(list(transid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
 item = c(232L, 123L, 232L, 234L, 435L, 435L, 453L, 454L)), .Names = 
 c("transid", "item"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```